# Writing $T:V \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$ as an inner product.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector inner product space over $\mathbb{F}$, and let $g:V \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$ be a linear transformation. Then there exists a unique vector $y \in V$ such that $g(x)=\langle x,y\rangle$.

This vector is found to be: $$y=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\overline{g(v_i)}v_i$$ Where $\{v_1,v_2,...v_n\}$ is an orthonormal basis for $V$. I think the intuition is basically:
\begin{align}
g(x)&=\langle x,y\rangle\\
g(x)&=\langle x, \sum{a_iv_i} \rangle \iff \\
g(v_j)&= \langle v_j, \sum{a_iv_i} \rangle \\
g(v_j)&=\overline{a_j}
\end{align}

Where I put the if and only if to indicate that the statement is true if and only if the basis vectors of the two linear transformations agree.

So this $y$ is determined by an orthonormal basis and the transformation and more over there is only one such $y$ for any linear transformation over an inner product space (From $V$ to $\mathbb{F}$).

My question is: Given A finite dimensional vector space $V$, and a linear transformation $T$, will $y$ be guaranteed different for different inner products over the same space? For example if we are considering $P^2(\mathbb{R})$ (the polynomials of up to degree two with real coefficients) with the inner product $\langle f,g \rangle= \int_0^1 f(t)g(t) \ dt$ and $g(f)=f(0)+f'(0),$ then we find that $g(f)=\langle f,210x^2-204x+33 \rangle.$ If I change this inner product (but remain in the same vector space), will $y$ be guaranteed to be different?

Or maybe I should ask:
let $T=x\cdot y$,   $T=x+y'$ (sorry bad notation)  be the representation of $T$ in the inner product space $(V, \cdot)$ and $(V,+)$, ($T:V \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$). Then, is it true that $y = y'$ if and only if $\cdot$ and $+$ are the same inner product?

Comment: I haven't heard of that theorem (my first time through Linear algebra), but I will look it up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given an n-dimensional real vector-space and a basis $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$, you can define an inner product by
$$
\langle x,y\rangle_e=\sum x_i y_i,
$$
if $x=\sum x_i e_i, y=\sum y_i e_i$. If we have another basis $\{e_1,f_2,\ldots,f_n\}$, it is clear that the linear functional $g(x)=\langle x,e_1\rangle_e=\langle x,e_1\rangle_f$ is represented by the same vector (namely $e_1$). So having the information for just one linear functional is not sufficient to ensure that two inner products agree.

[Edit] For the argument above to work, you actually need $\{e_1,f_2,\ldots,f_n\}$ to be an orthonormal basis with respect to $\langle .,.\rangle_e$. In dimension strictly larger than 1, such a choice can always be made. In dimension two, consider the two bases $\{e_1,e_2\},\{e_1,-e_2\}$, where $e_1$ and $e_2$ denotes the standard basis on $\mathbb R^2$ and $\langle.,.\rangle_e$ is the usual standard inner product (dot product).

On the other hand, if you have such information for all linear functionals (as opposed to just one), then it follows that $\langle x,y\rangle_e=\langle x,y\rangle_f$ for all $x,y\in V$ (since $x\mapsto \langle x,y\rangle_e$ is a linear functional which is represented by $y$ with respect to $\langle .,.\rangle_e$), which clearly implies that the two inner products agree.

Comment: does linear functional mean a linear transformation from $V$ to $\mathbb{F}$?

Comment: Yes, precisely so.

Comment: I am sorry its hard for me to follow your argument exactly but are you saying that the only difference between different inner products on a vector space is the basis? That is, if we have two different inner products on a finite dimensional vector space then there is a change of co ordinates matrix that allows us to convert back and forth?

Comment: More or less. Any basis induces an inner product in which the basis is orthogonal. On the other hand, any inner product has many bases which are orthogonal with respect to the inner product. So it is not a one-to-one correspondence.